# how to copy something from vim editor to shell command line

Tags: vim, copy, putty, paste

I intend to copy something from vim editor to shell command line. I have tried many ways, but I find all of them only work when in the same vim editor. My need is to copy and paste between vim editor and shell command line. That's, vim -> shell

PS: I am using putty.

EDIT:

BTW, what if just copy something from vim editor and paste it to terminal both in a unix/linux box?

ATTENTION:

output of :echo has("X11") in vim is 0, so my system does not support X11!

Comment: if you cannot use mouse middle button to paste `*` register, you could either save the text part into a temp file, or use other shell based tools (grep/sed/awk/....) to extract that part.

Comment: mouse middle button seems to do the paste work to vim eitor! That's not my need.

Comment: if middle button works, it could copy from vim->terminal. (if you have X installed).  you didn't explain that part in your question. you could try this line, if it worked, I will repost it as answer: in vim: select the lines, press: `"*y`, switch to your terminal, click mouse middle button.

Comment: I select the lines via "Ctrl+v", and then press "*y", I find "*y" does not work. Did you mean "y"? But, when I press "y" and use mouse middle button, it does not work. I meant mouse middle button can paste what in clipborad to vim editor, not to terminal.

Comment: I meant `"*y` it will yank selected text into `*` register, so that you can middle click to read it "anywhere" (not only in terminal)

Comment: * seems do match work in my vim environment. Sorry, does not work.

Comment: you press `double quote then star then y`! not `star y`

Comment: Ah, I connect a remote host, which is a linux box, via putty and open a vim editor in the remote host. My local host's OS is Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your vim version >= 7.3.74, you can set the vim to use the system clipboard by default by adding a line to your .vimrc:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

for the detail, see this [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard). Then you use the y(ank) command in vim, the content is in the system clipboard.

EDIT:
this solution and the "*y solution require the Vim that has clipboard support. Since you're lack of that, use cat/grep/less/tail... to extract the text you want to copy.

Comment: My trouble is that, I can paste what in clipboard to any file but fail to paste it to terminal(a putty window!)

Comment: yeah, but Shift+Insert key combination only works when paste to vim editor in putty.

Comment: It seems you want to copy from vim editor to the terminal, ***both of them are in the remote host opened in the putty***? If so, this would be impossible with putty alone since putty has no access to the system clipboard on the remote host, and clipboard on Windows host have no idea what you've copied. Maybe you need X11 forwarding thing or just use the mouse to select the content.

Comment: Ah, what if just copy something from vim editor and paste it to terminal both in a unix/linux box?

Comment: if you're using unix/linux box locally, not connecting it remotely, all these answers should work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47624/discussion-between-jfly-and-user2886717)

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>"</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd> to yank text in vim, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to paste in the terminal.

Comment: it seems that after pressing ctrl + shift + v, it will produce many things which I may not want.

Comment: @user2886717 Can you be more specific?  ctrl shift v just pastes what ever is on the "clipboard" to your terminal. Both of the classic ctrl + c/v commands can be used on the terminal simply by adding shift.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you pressing `+`? The `+` is there just to show that you need to press all three buttons at the same time, you don't actually press the `+` key to paste to terminal.

Comment: My system does not support X11, so I assume that's the cause of why all these solutions do not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

from the comments, it seems that your mouse middle button works for `*` buffer, you can select text in vim, then press: **3** keystrokes:

<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

and switch to other program, terminal, browser or whatever, click mouse middle to get yanked text.

read `:h y` for details, how to yank text and save in a specific register (in this case, it is register `*`)

Comment: My trouble is that, I can paste what in clipboard to any file but fail to paste it to terminal(a putty window!)

Answer (score 2):

### Using pipe

Select line[s] by using `V` command then execute this selection by command `:'<,'>w !sh`

Comment: May be it's not the right answer, because topic starter wants **copy** between `vim` and `shell`. But I come here from google by asking "vim copy content to shell execute" and found this solution cover my question completely

Comment: I liked the suggestion too. Use v to highlight something, then :w !somecmd gets the data piped to somecmd. Nice and easy.